# How to fix fatal error in magento causing wsod?

Tags: magento, fatal-error, magento-1.7, lightbox2, wsod

I'm using Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.2.

LightBox2 stopped working after clearing js/css cache via cache management.

I receive the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addItem() on a non-object in home/*******/public_html/app/code/community/IG/LightBox2/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Media/Gallery.php on line 163
```

The front-end now only shows WSOD / blank page.

I have tried:

- commenting out line 162 & 163,
- Clearing caches,
- Logging In/Out,
- Uncommenting line in index.php to display errors,
- disabling module,
- un/reinstalling via magento connect

Any suggestions on where else to go to debug this issue? Or should I just restore from backup?

Comment: given `$something->addItem()`, figure out where $something is NOT being defined properly. the reported line number is merely the first place that you tried to use this non-object improperly. the real error is elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcB

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_js', $js);

Comment: so $this is not being defined within the file Gallery.php? Line 162 is:

foreach ($this->_jsList as $js)

Comment: if $this isn't defined, then you'd have big problems, and would get `call to a member function getLayout` anyways. Most likely getBlock('head') isn't returning anything.

Comment: Is there any reason that getBlock('head') would not return anything? It is being referenced in the page.xml file here on line 73:
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

Comment: no idea. I don't do magento, but when you get a "X is not an object" thing, that's the first place I'd start looking.

Comment: Thanks Marc! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest reaching out to the people who developed you extension for support.  The better Magento extension shops and indie developers are always the best people to help you with a problem.

As for your specific problem, the code your error message is complaining about is here

```
foreach ($this->_jsList as $js)
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_js', $js);
```

Which means the call to `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')` is returning a non-object, mostly likely the boolean "false".

There's only three reasons I could think of for this happening.

1. You're using this on a page where Magento doesn't instantiate a "head" object
2. Some other customization you've made/module you've installed attempts to rewrite the `page/html_head` block class, but does so incorrectly such that Magento can't instantiate a `page/html_head' block
3. Some other customization you've made/module you've installed **removes** the head block

Lacking access to anyone with basic Magento skills, I'd start diff-ing your system and/or theme files vs. a standard installation.